# Exception "error MSB3024: Could not copy the file..." is thrown when attempting to build in DevOps pipeline using .Net Core 3.0 SDK (preview5)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-devops

I am attempting to build a `.Net Core 3.0 (preview)` project in a DevOps build pipeline.

The steps in my `azure-pipelines.yml` executes up to the "`docker build`" step, successfully initiating the build process.
The Docker file is read and executed up to the "dotnet build" step after which the following error is thrown.

> error MSB3024: Could not copy the file "/src/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.0/" to the destination file "/app/", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles. [/src/.csproj]

I have attempted to build locally by executing dotnet build ".csproj" -c Release -o /app
The build then succeeds with 0 errors and 0 warnings. Could this be related to an SDK issue in DevOps?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The build command from my Docker file.

```
RUN dotnet build "<project>.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

```
--- {OMITED}
---1ff83de4bdba
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /src
---Running in 972629766fad
Removing intermediate container 972629766fad
---1325ecd8e7c3
Step 6/16 : COPY ["<projectname>.csproj", "<projectname>/"]
---a4ba463683dc
Step 7/16 : RUN dotnet restore "<projectname>/<projectname>.csproj"
---Running in 82bb9095d412
Restore completed in 14.08 sec for /src/<projectname>/<projectname>.csproj.
Removing intermediate container 82bb9095d412
---7b0cc236782e
Step 8/16 : COPY . .
---884bb695bfb3
Step 9/16 : WORKDIR /src
---Running in 817b001e2060
Removing intermediate container 817b001e2060
---40b8690ecb63
Step 10/16 : RUN dotnet build "<projectname>.csproj" -c Release -o /app
---Running in 48d79b81c3cb
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.0.462+g62fb89029d for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Restore completed in 531.02 ms for /src/<projectname>.csproj.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview5-011568/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets(157,5): message NETSDK1057: You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview [/src/<projectname>.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview5-011568/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4560,5): error MSB3024: Could not copy the file "/src/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.0/<projectname>" to the destination file "/app/<projectname>", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles. [/src/<projectname>.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview5-011568/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4560,5): **error MSB3024: Could not copy the file "/src/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.0/<projectname>" to the destination file "/app/<projectname>", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles. **[/src/<projectname>.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:11.43
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet build "<projectname>.csproj" -c Release -o /app' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: docker build
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case the Assembly name of my project was the same as the name of the project and also the same as the directory name of that project. Once I changed the assembly name in the project properties to something else, this error was gone.

Comment: This helped me. My Solution name, project name and assembly name were same. Changing assembly name solved the problem.

Comment: Same for me. Thanks!

Comment: This was my problem as well.  This seems like MSFT could probably do a better job at communicating this error, though.  I was trying to follow along with the NServiceBus tutorial and ran into this with their sample project: https://docs.particular.net/tutorials/quickstart/?kme=nsb-getstarted-top

Comment: This issue was resolved by the above. I do not understand why this causes a problem in the build pipeline but seems to be a bug.

Comment: @DavidHirst Windows doesn't allow you to have two filesystem entries with the same name in one folder, it's not exactly a weird requirement :D The only thing the build pipeline could do about it is to put the folder in a different folder instead, but that's up to your configuration. Normally, the assembly would have a different name (X.dll or X.exe), this is just a bit of annoyance you get when you avoid using file extensions (like on nix systems).

Comment: you provided my an un-hoped solution. Thanks sir!

Answer (score 5):

in my case i had to rename the project folder to be different than the project itself in dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["<project-name>.csproj", "<project-name>_build/"]
RUN dotnet restore "<project-name>_build/<project-name>.csproj"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is an issue with the .Net Core 3.0 preview5 SDK. I have created the project in .Net Core 2.2 and it build successfully.

Comment: The issue is occurring with preview version 6 of SDK as well.  -    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview6-012264/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4552,5): error MSB3024: Could not copy the file "/src/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.0/xxx" to the destination file "/app/xxx", because the destination is a folder instead of a file. To copy the source file into a folder, consider using the DestinationFolder parameter instead of DestinationFiles. [/src/xxx.csproj]

Answer (score 0):

When adding the following parameters on the dotnet build command, the build succeeds in .Net Core 3.0

RUN dotnet build ".csproj" -c Release **-r linux-musl-x64** -o /app **--no-restore**

The DockerFile below built successfully in DevOps

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["<project-name>.csproj", "<project-name>/"]

RUN dotnet restore "<project-name>/<project-name>.csproj" -r linux-musl-x64
COPY  . "<project-name>/"
WORKDIR "/src/<project-name>"
RUN dotnet build "<project-name>.csproj" -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 -o /app --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "<project-name>.csproj" -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 -o /app --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<project-name>.dll"]
```